# Terraform bad policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Hello I have the following policy definition in my terraform, but it keeps returning as malformed

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "task-policy" {
  name   = "docker-flowcell-restore-task-policy"
  role   = "${aws_iam_role.task-role.id}"
  policy = "${file("${path.module}/policies/role-docker-flowcell-restore-${var.environment}-ecs-policy.json")}"
}
```

Been struggling with trying to find the error in this for awhile.

here is the error

```
aws_iam_role_policy.task-policy: Error putting IAM role policy docker-flowcell-restore-task-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Syntax errors in policy.
```

Here is the policy that is failing

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid":"AllowWritesS3",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:RestoreObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "Temp_name_for_post",
        "Temp_name_for_post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "SID": "Allow for user for upload S3 bucket",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
      ],
      "Resource":[
        "temp_name_for_post",
        "temp_name_for_post"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This could be an error with the policy itself, is what is resolved for the policy variable a valid json/a valid policy? Posting the error might help.

Comment: I added the error to the post/ each of the files that it can be from for the role are properly formatted json files.

Comment: It looks like you iam policy is malformed. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html) are docs on iam syntax and grammar. Another option to see what is wrong with the policy would be to copy the contents of that file into the iam policy validator in the aws console.

Comment: I see so the error is in one of the JSON files that the task-policy is reading from?

Comment: That is what it looks like to me

Comment: To be more specific, whatever file `"${file("${path.module}/policies/role-docker-flowcell-restore-${var.environment}-ecs-policy.json")}"` resolves to

Comment: Hey Jeff i just uploaded a copy of the file that it is be resolved to

Comment: That all caps `SID` is what is getting you, it should be `Sid` and I am pretty sure spaces are not allowed in that value so something like `"AllowForUserUploadS3Bucket"` would work . Hope that gets you off the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately AWS doesn't tell you exactly what the syntax errors are, so you have to find them yourself. Sometimes you can do this by eye; other times you may just want to use the AWS Console as Jeffrey suggested - and perhaps take out each statement one-by-one then re-validate, to see where the error lies (it's a lot quicker than waiting for Terraform to finish).

In your case, you need to:

- change `SID` to `Sid` in your second statement
- change the `Sid` value in that second statement so it has no spaces in it (eg. `"AllowForUserForUploadS3Bucket"`)
- use valid S3 ARNs instead of `"temp_name_for_post"`, such as `"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"` to refer to all objects in a bucket named `my-bucket`

After changing these items, the policy now validates for me via the AWS Console.

Comment: Hey Tim, Would you mind pointing me in the direction of the policy validator?

Comment: Sure thing, it's not a standalone validator as such, you basically just jump into the [IAM policy section](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/policies), create a new policy, select the JSON tab, and paste in your policy text. Click Review Policy and then it will tell you if there's any issues. If it proceeds to the next screen you're all good (and you don't have to save it).

Comment: This validation is helpful, but beware that "Policy Validator only checks JSON policy syntax and grammar. It does not validate that your ARNs, action names, or condition keys are correct." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_policy-validator.html Another tool you can use once it validates is the Policy Simulator: https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your iam policy is malformed. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html) are docs on iam syntax and grammar. Another option to see what is wrong with the policy would be to copy the contents of that file into the iam policy validator in the aws console. The Sid field is not required, but if present it must be unique in the policy, and it cannot contain spaces.